# 2 HTML forms with same submit - POST through values from both

Tags: php, jquery

Ok , maybe a hard one to explain. I have a form that is built using [PHP Form Builder Class](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc2.0-php5/index.php#project-overview)

Which looks like:

```
$form = new form("firstForm");
    $form->setAttributes(array(
             "width" => 600,
             "noAutoFocus" => 1,
             "jsIncludesPath" => "lib/php-form-builder-class/includes",
             "action" => "uploader.php"
    ));

    $form->addTextbox("Enter a Title:", 'title' , $row['title']);
    $form->addTextbox("Enter a Promo Code:", "promo" , $row['promo']);
    $form->addWebEditor("Description", "description", $row['description'], array("basic" => 1));
    $form->addWebEditor("Terms and Conditions", "terms", $row['terms'], array("basic" => 1));
    $form->addHidden("img_urls", $row['img_urls']);
    $form->addHidden("destination", $row['destination']);
    $form->addHidden("header", $row['headerimg']);
    $form->addHidden("cmd", "submit_0");
    $form->addButton();
    $form->render();
```

I want to add some jQuery to one of the elements to allow drag and drop,  so I've made another form element:

```
?>
    <form id="firstForm"  action="uploader.php" method="post" >
    <ul class="sortable"> 
    Mags Select:
    <?
    foreach ($profiles as $mag) {
    ?>
    <div id="sorty"><input type="checkbox" name="units" value="<? echo $mag ?>" /><label><? echo $mag ?></label><br /></div>
    <? }  ?>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

How can I make the jQuery part post through its values 'units' when the PHP Form Builder Class is submitted?

Ive had a look at adding a method to the class, but wondered if there was an easier way?

EDIT:

The PHP Form Builder Class form is self contained, so wherever the jQuery form is in the page, it will always be outside the other.

Comment: Why make another form? Just add your elements to the original form so they submit the values along with it.

Comment: Ah, didnt explain that when the PHP Form is generated, it is self contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript and transfer the values from the second form INTO (hidden fields in) the first form?

Or similarly you could just build the form and copy the HTML (view source) and use that instead of the raw php, then slot your jQuery drag and drop thing into it that way.

Comment: an inelegant solution ,(I mean that in no way disrespectfully!) but I did your second answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just change your second "firstForm" id to secondForm then do something like this:

```
$('#firstForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var postData = $(this).add('#secondForm').serialize();

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), postData, function() {
     // Complete....
    }
});
```

As your `units` input has multiple elements, you can change this to an array like so (take note of change from `units` to `units[]`):

```
<div id="sorty"> <!-- I assume this should be ouside the foreach... !-->
   <? foreach ($profiles as $mag) { ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="units[]" value="<? echo $mag ?>" />
      <label><? echo $mag ?></label><br/>
   <? } ?>
</div>
```

Then you'll receive this just like an array in PHP:

```
 foreach ($_POST['units'] as $key => $value)
 {

 }
```

Comment: I tried this : <script type="text/javascript">
$('#firstForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var postData = $(this).add('#secondForm').serialize();

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), postData, function() {
     window.location = "uploader.php"
    }
 
)});
</script>  but the window redirect never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not have your jQuery drag-and-drop form field in the same `<form>` tag as all the other fields? That’s the natural way to do it.

Comment: I'm guessing he can't put custom HTML/jQuery into forms made using the php form class?

Comment: Without adding another custom method to the class, I cannot think how to add the 'jQuery' form to the PHP one.

Comment: @BobFlemming: the jQuery field is just made up of checkboxes and that `<ul>`, right? Could you not add the checkboxes to the form via PHP Form Builder, then put the `<ul>` after the form? (I’m not familiar with PHP Form Builder, so apologies if this isn’t possible.)